# How do I migrate my SharePoint 2007 environment to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: upgrade

I'm looking for a book or website which will lay out the complete process of upgrading from SharePoint 2007 to 2010.

I've come across a couple of products which will do this for me, such as Xavor and Metalogix, but they are both quite expensive.

Our Sharepoint 2007 environment is only 5gb in size so I don't think we should need one of these expensive products to do the upgrade.

Can somebody point me to a book or website which will completely outline the process of going through this upgrade?

I found a book from O'Reilly Media which goes through the process but it isn't due out until December 2011 so that's not going to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a production for this. We migrated 5 applications (about 5 GB each) manually and we did not face any major issues.

Comment: I don't necessarily need one, just looking for literature on how to do the upgrade manually that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a shameless plug to my own [whitepaper](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint-2010/whitepaper-on-sharepoint-upgrade/) on upgrading SharePoint from 2007 to 2010 ;-)

Joel Oleson had a book planned (that included chapters in my whitepaper), but I think it was delayed. You can access parts of it for free for 45 days [here](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=359). In the meantime check his [blog](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=306).

You should also check the planning guidance on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420.aspx).

Also SharePoint 911 have created a [wiki](http://www.sharepointupgrade.com/default.aspx) dedicated to SharePoint upgrade.

Comment: +1, impressive whitepaper.  I only had a chance to glance at it, but I will give it a more thorough reading when I have some time.

Answer (score 3):

We recently did this and it was a bit of a nightmare.  Keep in mind that we were dealing with a really screwed up 2007 instance to begin with and that we were in the 1 terabyte range rather than 5 gigabytes.  I doubt your migration will be as difficult as ours.

There are too many points to hit regarding migration to cover in one post so I will direct you to TechNets article [Upgrade and Migration for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214) which I think is a good place to start and should cover most questions you have.

Comment: Both were great answers but I thought the other was a bit more comprehesive. Thanks for taking the time to provide such a great answer!